# Getting value from sublist on Netsuite

Tags: javascript, json, netsuite

I'mn trying to get a value from a sublist on a record in Netsuite, but I can´t seem to get th evalue I only get null. This is what I'm doing:

First I get the record with nlapiLoadRecord

```
fulfillment = nlapiLoadRecord('itemFulfillment', '102568');
```

The I get the itemCount of the sublist:

```
var itemCount = fulfillment.getLineItemCount('item');
```

The I make a loop to get the values, but here is what returns all null values:

```
for(var y = 1; y <= itemCount; y++){
    info += fulfillment.getLineItemValue('items', 'custcol_old_material_num', i) + " ";
}
```

The fullfillment object I get is the next one:

```
fulfillment:{
  "finalshipto": "text",
  "shipstatus": {
    "internalid": "C",
    "name": "Shipped"
  },
  ......
  ......
  ......
  "item": [  <--this is what I want to access
    {
      "custcol_calculated_weight": 835.2,
      "custcol_item_weight ": 17.4,
      "custcol_old_material_num": "56624210655084",
      "description": "1x1x-xxxx TEXT", <---this is the data I want to print
      "excludefromraterequest": false,
      "inventorydetail": {
        "itemdescription": "1x1x-xxxx TEXT",
        "item": {
          "internalid": "xxxx",
          "name": "xxxxxxx"
        },
        "unit": {
          "internalid": "1",
          "name": "TEXT"
        },
        "quantity": xx,
        "inventoryassignment": [
          {
            "binnumber": {
              "internalid": "xxxx",
              "name": "TEXT"
            },
            "quantity": 48,
            "quantityavailable": 48
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Unless you mis-typed your row increment variable is `y` but you are indexing the row with `i`

Comment: and also the sublist name is `item` not `items`. It's the sort of thing I often really wish Netsuite would throw an error for.

Comment: The i variable was a typo, but you were right it was item, not items. Thanks!!